# Extracting values from an interpolating function

Tags: differential-equations, interpolation

I'm an absolute beginner using *Mathematica* just to solve a pair of non-linear ODEs and I'm struggling a bit with the lingo. The solutions come out as `x -> InterpolatingFunction[-]`, `y -> InterpolatingFunction[-]`. Both are functions purely of time.

All I want to do now is to extract a few values from these (or the corresponding plots if easier), namely gradients at certain points, and points with certain gradients. Things like `Grad` and `FindMaximum` don't seem to work.

Can anyone help? Even if its just a bit of code I can copy to get them?

Here is what I have so far:

```
s = NDSolve[{x'[t] == -(y[t]^-1) x[t]^(7/2) (0.99*10^-9) - y[t] x[t]^(-1/2) (0.24*10^-3), 
             y'[t] == x[t]^(5/2) (0.99*10^-9) - (y[t]^2) (x[t]^(-3/2)) (1.21*10^-3), 
             x[0] == 1.5*10^7, y[0] == 10^10},
            {x, y}, {t, 0, 4000}]
```

Two ODEs with initial conditions and time boundaries.

And I plot it

```
TP = Plot[x[t] /. s, {t, 0, 400}]
NP = Plot[y[t] /. s, {t, 0, 400}]
```

Comment: I'm missing the actual question, perhaps, but `NDSolve[]` returns a function you can differentiate. For instance: `yf = y /. First[NDSolve[{y'[x] == -y[x], y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 1}]]; Table[yf'[x], {x, 0, 1, 1/10}]`

Comment: Can you provide some code of your specific problem?

Comment: code now included

Answer (score 3):

I may be misunderstanding your question here, but it appears to me that `FindMaximum` etc work quite well with your interpolating functions.

For instance, using the solutions `s` as defined by your code, we can plot e.g. `y[t]` that has a clear maximum:

```
Plot[y[t] /. s, {t, 0, 400}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Clearly the function has a maximum for $t$ around 100. We can use [`FindMaximum`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindMaximum.html), [`FindArgMax`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindArgMax.html), or [`NArgMax`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NArgMax.html) to find the value of `t` for which the maximum arises:

```
FindMaximum[y[t] /. s, t]
(* Out: {2.35387*10^10, {t -> 119.186}} *)

FindArgMax[y[t] /. s, t]
(* Out: {119.186} *)
```

[`NArgMax`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NArgMax.html) needs the most hand-holding: first, it doesn't like its argument to be a list, so we use `y[t] /. First@s` to extract only the interpolation function, instead of a list of one item. Second, its initial guess leads it to evaluate the interpolation function outside of its domain; we prevent that by imposing constraints on the value of $t$ that are well within the interpolation domain and close to the max.

```
NArgMax[{y[t] /. First@s, 100 < t < 400}, t]
(* Out: 119.186 *)
```

As you can see all results agree.

---

You can also obtain derivatives directly from the interpolation functions as `y'[t] /. s`. For instance:

```
Plot[y'[t] /. s, {t, 0, 400}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You could also look for that maximum directly by finding the zeroes of the first derivative:

```
FindRoot[(y'[t] /. s) == 0, {t, 100}]
(* Out: {t -> 119.186} *)
```